# Fetch data from multiple collection of same structure in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have month wise collection of user game logs record.
For each months game played by user stored in game_(year+month) collection in mongo db. Now I want to fetch data of game played by user from last 2-4-5-6 months.  collection structure is :

```
game_201801 :[
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 123, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'} }, 
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 125, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Raise'} }, 
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 126, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Bet'} }, 
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 127, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'} }, 
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 128, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Raise'} }, 
{name : 'Kohli', gameId : 129, uid : 18, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'}}, 
{name : 'Bhuvi', gameId : 130, uid : 15, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'}}
];

game_201802 : [
{name : 'Dhawan', gameId : 131, uid : 25 , gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'} },
{name : 'Rohit', gameId : 132, uid : 45,  gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'}},
{name : 'Ashwin',gameId : 133,  uid : 99, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'}},
{name : 'Raina', gameId : 134, uid : 48, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Fold'}},
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 135, uid : 7,  gameLog : {userTurn: 'Raise'} ,
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 136, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Raise'} ,
{name : 'Dhoni', gameId : 137, uid : 7, gameLog : {userTurn: 'Raise'} ];
```

I want to fetch game-logs data of Dhoni of Id :7 from both collection (game_201801 & game_201802) in one mongo query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query multiple collections at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search on multiple collections in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056903/search-on-multiple-collections-in-mongodb)